# Best practice for visualizing a lift from zero?

Tags: data-visualization, interpretation, measurement

Let's say you have two columns of data. Column A represents a value you had last month, and column B represents a value you have this month. If you want the percent change between the two, you math it:

```
(new - old) / old
```

or, in many languages and tools, preventing a division by zero error:

```
if old = 0 then 0 else (new - old) / old
```

However, if you had zero last month and something this month, that's good news depending on what the story is, so outputting zero may not be the best thing to show. Is there a "best practice" for visualizing a lift from zero in the context of a percent change in this situation?

- `Zero` seems wrong.
- `100%` seems wrong.
- `Inf.` seems wrong.
- `N/A` seems wrong.
- `DIV0` seems wrong.

Comment: This entirely depends on what the data actually represents. The limit of the ratio f(x)/g(x) as g(x) approaches 0 depends on what f(x) and g(x) are.

Comment: I would say that what depends is not the limit of the ratio but one's interpretation of that ratio.

Answer (score 1):

If zero is a common value, then percent change may not be a good metric. If it's rare, it seems reasonable to mark such percent changes as "N/A" or whatever your system uses for missing values. The percent change is literally "Not Applicable".